# How do I set a variable in Twig if a value exists more than once in a loop?

Tags: templating, forloop

How do I loop through entries and set a variable if there are any duplicates in the data I'm checking?

In my case, I need to check if there are more than one entry per year. The variable I'm setting will be used in a conditional later in the template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be accomplished by creating an array of the entry years. Inside the loop that's building the array, a conditional checks if the year already exists in the array... if the year exists, a variable is set to TRUE which you can use in your conditional later down on the page.

```
{% set files = craft.entries.section("downloads") %}
{% set dropdown = 0 %}
{% set yearArray = [] %}

{% for entry in files %}
    {% set year = entry.fileDate | date('Y') %}
    {% if year in yearArray %}
        {% set dropdown = 1 %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set yearArray = yearArray | merge([year]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% if dropdown %}
    Do this
{% else %}
    Do this
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Craft's [`group`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter:

```
{% set files = craft.entries.section("downloads") | group('fileDate.year'} %}
{% set dropdown = false %}

{% for year, filesInYear in files %}
    {% if filesInYear|length > 1 %}
        {% set dropdown = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```